# Why do some functions, or at least, PowersRepresentations, run far faster on subsequent calls? What determines this behaviour?

Tags: performance-tuning, number-theory, built-in-symbols

Say I run the following:

```
PowersRepresentations[4782969,4,2]
```

and it takes about 2 minutes. If I call it again it takes only about 0.0005 seconds.

What determines this? If I was crazy how do I stop this and have it run much longer as in the first call?

Is there a list of functions that do this? Is there a criteria for a built-in function to run faster on subsequent calls?

Comment: Many functions in Mathematica have some sort of in-session [caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)) of results for results corresponding to specific inputs. Another such function is `FullSimplify`. The purpose of this, unsurprisingly, is to trade memory usage for running time - that is getting repeated results faster while using a bit more memory in order to provide them quickly.

Comment: @kirma Yeah, obviously that is going on - I was wondering is there a list of such functions.

Comment: I don't believe providing an exhaustive list is possible because functions call other functions in the system...

Comment: @1729taxi nothing so obvious on Kirma's answer given that you didn't say so in your question. A bit more appreciation for the free help you are getting wouldn't harm anybody. Moving the goalpost on the other hand, no so nice.

Comment: @kirma After the drive by shooting post from someone else - Yeah, I've never seen such a list so I expect there isn't one. The reason I ask is that this behaviour led me astray in debugging some code - I couldn't understand why timings had changed quite drastically.

Comment: Relying on timings of symbolic functions is often hard due to this - just restarting kernel gives a better picture of the situation. In the case of machine-precision evaluation it tends to be much more predictable.

Comment: @kirma That's what I did - restart the kernel for consistent timings - the PowersRepresentations was buried - and not always called - so I was confused for a while. I first noted this a year or two ago - then forgot about the issue until recently.

Comment: @kirma and 1729: if you suspect caching is involved somewhere in your timing tests, `ClearSystemCache[]` might be useful in checking.

Comment: @J.M.'spersistentexhaustion I almost mentioned this earlier - that doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: It seems to me that the [number-theory] tag is appropriate for a question about a number-theoretic function, and it would be helpful to others if the question were so tagged.

Comment: As Michael notes, you are specifically asking about a number-theoretic function, so it looks to me that [tag:number-theory] is warranted.

Answer (score 6):

Try unsetting the internal memoization:

```
NumberTheory`PowersRepresentationsDump`powersRepresentation[4782969, 4, 2] =.
```

When `PowersRepresentations[4782969,4,2]` is first called, it autoloads some code and saves the result in the internal function.  The code for `powersRepresentation` may be inspected after the package it loaded.